# Running the program with custom environment variables (C / Windows 10)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-10

I started to learn WinAPI recently, and one of the first tasks is to create the program that runs another program (this second program just prints the environment variables and its arguments) and gives the custom environment variables to it. These custom environment variables should be specified in file.
I wrote the following code in C, but it doesn't work. I get the runtime error "msys-1.0.dll isn't intalled..."
What's wrong? I use Visual Studio 2015 to compile this code. GCC compiles it too but it seems that program just do nothing (even doesn't show the error message).
Problem disappears if I add my custom variables to variables of the parent process. I see all variables. But if give only custom variables, I see this error message.
Help me, please!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ENV_STR_LEN 2000
#define FILE_NAME_LEN 100
#define ENV_NUM 256

void run_program(char * program_name, char * env){
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    program_name,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    (LPVOID) env,           // 
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi );
}

int main(int argn, char ** args, char **environment) {
    FILE * f = fopen("vars", "r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }

    char pr_name [] = "task1.exe";

    char * allenvs = (char *)malloc(ENV_NUM * ENV_STR_LEN * sizeof(char));
    char * j = allenvs;
    while(!feof(f)) {
        fscanf(f, "%s", j);
        j += strlen(j) + 1;
    }
    *j = '\0';
    run_program(pr_name, allenvs);

    return 0;
}
```

The content of "vars":

```
uyuih=gfhjlkjgdlsj
jgk=tdfdsfsd
dfdl=5664
rrrr=ttyfdf
```

Comment: You are not retaining important variables like `PATH`. You should likely be appending to the environment rather than replacing it. Your code needs to read the existing environment block, and then add your new variables to the end. You also need to put some work in to avoid buffer overrun, which your program is currently susceptible to. And you should also be aware that you are leaking the memory allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: I thougth about necessity of PATH variable. Is it really vital for MS Windows application? The similar code works in Linux properly.

What about memory allocation, it's important, I know. I'll fix it. Thanks)

Comment: It depends on the application, and how it is installed and linked, what the `PATH` requirements are. It seems pretty clear that you are missing some essential environment variable.

Comment: msys is part of mingw. It does not seem you are running a plain visual studio compiled program. Are you sure you are running the same thing you are compiling?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure.
I'll try o run this program on another PC

Comment: It's the other program that is linked to msys isn't it? I still can't see why you don't realise that the environment that you pass to the new process is the issue.

Comment: I realized that and fixed my code a bit.
Maybe it's linked to msys, but I can't realize why it is so. I've created an empty project in VS and attached one .c file to it. Does VS link to msys by default?

Comment: It is not at all unusual for a process to fail to run if PATH is not defined.  That is almost certainly your problem.